# Started a new RDS instance, and fees went ballistic (well, nearly) for some reason?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-billing

Created a new RDS MySQL t3.micro server to use for development purposes and testing. Total cost is supposed to be $0.026 per hour for a Standard, Single-AZ instance of this type in my selected region which means around $18.72 per month.

For some reason, my billing graph shows an increased cost of around $13 PER DAY since I started up the server?

[image: AS costs]

I have shut it down temporarily, but does someone know what could be causing this? No other changes have been made to my AWS environment.

UPDATE: It seems APS1-RDS:PIOPS jumped for some reason, and I'm not sure if it is related? Even though the DB is shut down, the billing is continuing?

[image]

Comment: How much storage did you provision and are you sure these are RDS-Costs? Check the cost explorer for details.

Comment: @Maurice it seems the APS1-RDS:PIOPS totally JUMPED on that day? What would cause that? The daily $10-$13 is still nabbing generated even thought the server is shut down?

Comment: EBS-Volumes still incur costs even if the instance is shut down. Those are especially high for the io1/io2 volume types.

Comment: @Maurice just noticed that the DB is Provisioned IOPS SSD (io1) as storage, and IOPS is set to 3000. Should fix the issue if I switch the storage type right?

Comment: It should at least reduce it significantly - provisioned IOPS means very fast storage at relatively high cost ;-)

Comment: @Maurice switched to General Purpose Ssd, let's see if it works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stop an RDS database, only some of the fees stop.

The cost of the EBS volumes that store your data will continue to accrue even if the instance they're attached to is not running.

In your case, you chose a high-performance storage option (Provisioned IOPS SSDs), which dwarves the cost of the instance running, so by shutting down the instance, you didn't actually reduce the cost significantly.

Switch the volume to a more reasonable GP2 or GP3 volume and the costs should go down significantly. Almost no dev-System will need provisioned IOPS SSDs.

Comment: Just switched to General Purpose SSD. Hopefully that will do the trick! Will wait a day or two then mark this as the answer if ever.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you stop your RDS instance, you will be charged for the EBS volume attached to it. Depending on your EBS volume size & type the charges will vary.

The io1/2 volumes are much costlier than gp2/gp3. So if possible, change the type of volumes.

Also, you mentioned you have stopped the RDS temporarily. Just a note - If you stop RDS, AWS will auto-turn it on in a week's time for auto maintenance & backup. Just ensure it's shutdowns after that else, you will again incur the charges.